# Spin Tool behaves unexpected

Tags: modifiers

I import points from a .csv and connect them with a single line. After that I Spin them 360 degrees/steps. Deselect and Reselect all vertices. Click Remove Doubles. Unfortunately the mesh is not only non Manifold but also the resulting non manifold vertices are not constant. Here a screenshot of the upper part, where one can see that not all of the vertices are non manifold. 
[image: Upper][image: Upper loop][image: Lower Loop]

I did the exact thing already and it worked the first time. I don't understand why it gives me this error. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be linked to the removes doubles treshold. Try to increase it a little to compensate computation errors when making the spin. (Not sure the 360° spin will be a perfect 360)

Comment: That was it. Thx a million!